# How to create new pandas column based on other column of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a following df:

```
  id1      id2     id3(expected_col)
   21       4          21a
   21       4          21a
   21       4          21a 
   21       5          21b
   22       6          22a
   22       6          22a
   22       6          22a
   23       7          23a
   23       7          23a
   23       8          23b
   23       9          23c
```

There are two columns- id1 and id2, I want to create a new column producing id3 which kind of combination of the two previous columns.

The integer part is same as the id1 column, but I want to add string which changes whenever **id2** changes, and then the alphabetical cycle starts again with "a" whenever new **id1** is encountered.

So maybe we can grouby id1 and then perform rest of the operation, but I am not sure how to generate the string alphabets for the new column. In the above df id3 is the resultant column I expect.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a GroupBy-Apply approach, with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) used at the group level on 'id2' to determine changes, then mapping against [`ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) letters.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def combine_ids(grp, letters):
    grp = grp.ne(grp.shift()).cumsum() - 1
    return str(grp.name) + grp.map(letters)

letters = pd.Series(list(ascii_lowercase))
df['id3'] = df.groupby('id1')['id2'].apply(combine_ids, letters)
```

The above assumes you only need up to 26 letters to append.  If you need more, you could use a procedure similar to below to add repeated letters 'aa' - 'zz':

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

doubles = map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2))
letters = pd.Series(list(ascii_lowercase) + list(doubles))
```

The resulting output:

```
    id1  id2  id3
0    21    4  21a
1    21    4  21a
2    21    4  21a
3    21    5  21b
4    22    6  22a
5    22    6  22a
6    22    6  22a
7    23    7  23a
8    23    7  23a
9    23    8  23b
10   23    9  23c
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect !